# sqlalchemy: connect to MySQL without password

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have MySQL base "test" with no password on root. I can log in there

```
mysql -uroot test # all fine
```

I want to access it with `sqlalchemy`. I try with those URLs:

```
mysql+mysqldb://root@localhost/test

mysql+mysqldb://root:@localhost/test
```

But both of them fail with error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError)
    (1045, "Access denied for user
    'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)") None None
```

How should I access the base without a password?

**Edit**

I tried also:

```
mysql://root@/test
mysql+mysqldb://root@/test
```

With a local dummy account *with* password, it works without problems.

Answer (score 4):

Try: 
`mysql://root@localhost/test?`

specifically: 
    `engine = create_engine('mysql://root@localhost/test?')`

Answer (score 2):

the equivalent sqlalchemy url to what you have on the command line is

```
mysql://root@/test
```

MySQL consideres the root user connecting over the standard unix socket (no `-h` in the command line client) to be a different user than the same username connecting via tcp

Comment: I haven't actually checked this with mysql, but I can confirm that this solves the problem with a postgresql db (where passwordless `psql dbname` works)